# How to create and start SignalR hub connection in a C# class

Tags: c#, .net-core, signalr

I am working with a .NET core application. My requirement is that i have to call SignalR method from a C# class and then update the data on front end by a callback in javascript. How can i create and start the SignalR hub connection in a C# class.

Comment: well when the page first loads on the client side, you need to save the connection id of the user in db on the on 'connection' event handler. after that call the hub from c# pass the connection Id and then the data will be sent to that user.

Comment: also add some code , showing what work you have done until now

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio-code) to create your SignalR services.

If you need to send invocation to the front-end within your own service, you must resolve [`IHubContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.ihubcontext-1) to access the hub instead of the hub itself. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-2.2) for details

Comment: var connection = new HubConnection("http://127.0.0.1:5010/");
var hubProxy = connection.CreateHubProxy("LiveDataHub");
connection.Start().Wait();
hubProxy.Invoke("GetUpdatedDataFromServer");
This is what i have currently done. But i am getting the error "AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred."

Comment: Your "connection" seems to be the access to the hubs from the server-side, though  "hub connection" is defined as the client. @WaleedNaveed

Comment: If you get aggregate exceptions which is a pack of multiple exceptions, debug it and refer to the every single exceptions inside it. @WaleedNaveed

Comment: So, what is your front-end application? you seem to have a web front-end since you said there was a javascript callback but you are now giving a code that is for the client side .NET applcation.

Comment: Let me give you an example: Consider this method:
public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
        }
I want to call that "Send" method from some class in C# and the "broadcastMessage" will be a callback in javascript to update web page

Comment: If you need to send message from the server-side application to the client-side or web front-end, you need to resolve `IHubContext` from your server-side application container, instead of using a client-side connection API.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193617/discussion-between-waleed-naveed-and-alsein).